# Can I open Coda 2.5 in safe mode (mac air, yosemite 10.10.5)

Tags: javascript, osx-yosemite, coda

Coda is crashing as I try to debug some javascript. I force quit and even restart but it is unusable. Has anyone else had this? Is there any way to open Coda in safe mode and close the offending js file?

(I've opened the mac in safe mode but the problem persists.)

Thanks

Emma

PS. And is there a better/more robust app or way to debug my js? This is driving me crazy. Is dreamweaver better? I would pay 17 quid a month while debugging if it would help...

Comment: i would contact Panic for support instead of asking here.

Comment: Thanks. I already have. I figured someone else must have had the same experience.

Comment: I'd use the [Chrome Dev Tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools), but this is probably not the right kind of question for stackoverflow...

Answer (score 0):

Hold shift down while double clicking on the application name from your apps list within Finder (not from the shortcut bar).

I still have no idea why Coda has such a problem with this code though. I would love to know any reasons or better software.